# Gated content: Asking users to fill in a short survey(2-5 questions) before allowing to download a free product

Tags: forms, data-collection, questionnaire, demographics

We are currently working on updating our website. all products we have require a user login as they all communicate with our cloud. So to use any of our products users will still need to sign up for an id via the website. however some products are free and some are subscription or license based.

We would like to collect some demographic information about our users but at the same time keep the sign up process fast and simple. We have good idea already who uses our premium products but little about people who use our free product range.

We thinking of adding a pop up survey with (2-5 questions) that would be triggered when user tries to download a free product. Which creates a gated content and from looking at information above it seems like this is a bad choice. this download doesn't need to require login as premium products because of absence of subscription but user will need to have an account set up to use the free product anyway.

What would be the best way to combine this data collection while keeping sign up and login process to minimum input but at the same time avoid gated content, should we just keep questions to a minimum and add them to sign up or maybe reach out directly via free app ui to fill in the form?

Any leads will be much appreciated

Comment: I’m worried you are going to get a lot of trash data from people who rush through the survey by giving unrevealing data. I know that’s what I usually do when I get confronted with things like this. Bart Simpson has downloaded quite a lot of software thanks to me. Have you considered how to mitigate or account for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would be concerned that using a pop-up or intercept form whenever the user decides to download the free product would lead to user abandonment ("Oh, now I have to fill out a form? Forget it.").

If the free product is a limited or demo version of another product offered on your website, I feel it's appropriate to ask them for a short set of questions, but I would do this **before** they download. An advantage here is you can track conversions (who completes the form and goes through with the download) and make any necessary adjustments to the form and the questions it contains.

Another, more limited method you could consider is your website analytics platform. Google Analytics, for example, can track additional demographic information depending on what set of cookies/tracking you enable. It's certainly not perfect (and may not match the data you're hoping to track), but it would at least give you some insight into who is triggering the download on your website without asking them for information using a form or otherwise setting up a "gate."

One last point: you mentioned that your products talk to the cloud. If the free products also require this connection to work properly, then you'll have to use a form regardless.

I hope this information is helpful to you.

Comment: I agree with "_Oh, now I have to fill out a form? Forget it._", but for me it would apply almost as much prior to getting to the download link as if it hijacked the download link... unless your product was the only one of the kind that fulfilled a specific need, if I'm trying free/demo apps, I'd just move on to the next one. @ntnlbd: you're probably better having the software ask once it's been installed and used for a bit (similar to the "Rate me" reminders in some mobile apps). Conversion might be low, but higher than if no one downloaded in the first place!

Comment: Thank you guys this was helpful, we have though about including the survey in the software itself.